# angular добавить слэш в конце

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

Здраствуйте, каким образом в ангуляр добавить слэш в конце?
Например роут:
web.com/blog должен стать web.com/blog/

если в роуте сделать "page/." то это сработает и можно зайти на web.com/page/ но если этот роут главный в модуле,
То не выходит перейти на web.com/page

```js
 {
  path: "",
  component: BlogListComponent,
 },
```

Пробовал гуглить по слову trailing slash end и тд, не смог найти нормальный вариант чтоб он работал

Comment: Не понятно, для чего это нужно? Можно узнать причину, возможно для вашей проблемы есть другое решение

Comment: Так сказали сделать СЕОшники,сам не понимаю зачем им это